# Remove href attr and add action="1004"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have context menu, on right click on link I have fetched its HTML using below code:

```
thisDiv = target_element.parent().html();
```

`console.log(thisDiv)` is:

```
<a href="http://goo.com" class="sim-row-edit" data-type="link">goo</a>
```

How can I remove attribute `href` and add attribute `action="1004"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **removeAttr** jquery function for remove attr.

```js
target_element.parent().removeAttr('href');
```

for add attribute **attr** function.

```js
target_element.parent().attr('action', '1004');
```

Comment: target_element.removeAttr('href').attr('action', '1004');

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".sim-row-edit").removeAttr("href").attr("action","1004");
```

Comment: this is changing all links in the page with this class

Comment: give your element one extra class or id & make it selector

Comment: not possible, i have to do something with event target

Comment: target_element.removeAttr('href').attr('action', '1004'); worked

Comment: set this as answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Just remove href attribute using removeAttr("href") and then add the new attribute attr("action","1004").

**selector.removeAttr("href").attr("action","1004");**